# How to know whether JLabel is selected or clicked on using Swing?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jsplitpane

I am working with `JSplitPane`. The left pane contains 3 `JLabel` objects (`Add Jar`, `TestCase`, `TestSuite`) and right pane contains `Add` button.  So in my case when I select any one of the labels and click `Add` (in right pane) `TestCase` screen should load. But I am facing problem in finding which label is selected or clicked.

I Have tried many ways and one with the following code, but couldn't succeed as it checks for 1st condition every time I click Add button as `isEnabled()` will be `true` by default and checked with by setting it to `false` (couldn't succeed).

Here is the code:

```
public void AddActionPerformed(){
if(jLabel2.isEnabled())
{
      System.out.println("-------------"+jLabel2.getText());
      new TestCasesFrame().setVisible(true);             
}
   if(jLabel3.isEnabled()) {
    System.out.println("Test Suiteeeeeeee Clicked"+jLabel3.getText());
    new TestSuitesFrame().setVisible(true);                
} 
}
```

Comment: *"So in my case when i select any one of the the JLabel(TestCase) and click Add(in Right Pane) TestCase screen should load"* - It sounds like [JList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) or [JRadioButton](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#radiobutton) are better options than labels..

Comment: You should use RadioButton   instead of Label

Comment: BTW - this has nothing to do with your IDE and everything to do with `JLabel`.  Don't add irrelevant tags to questions.

Comment: @NeerajJain Hi Neeraj Jain Thanks for giving me a simple idea which is working beautiful and i can do whatever with radio buttons..for Ex:- jRadioButton1.setSelected(false) and jRadioButton1.isSelected()...Thanks a lot once again but i am not sure whether my team will cope with radio buttons or list...

Comment: @AndrewThompson Hi Andrew i got the solution for my question... Adding irrelevant tags was not my question... Instead U could have helped me with some good ideas...